# Координаты круга с сохранением в файл в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Не получается сохранить координаты круга. Суть игры найти круг по звуку. Задание - пользователь может загрузить потом игру где остановился.

```
 private void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\soh.txt"); //указываем путь к файлу.
                                                                   double x = MainCanvas.GetLeft(target);
                                                                   double y = MainCanvas.GetTop(target);
           /* foreach (Ellipse rect in MainCanvas.Children.OfType<Ellipse>())
            {
                double x = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
                double y = Canvas.GetTop(rect);
           }*/
                writer.WriteLine(x);
                writer.WriteLine(y);
                writer.Close();
            }
```

Это мои попытки, а это класс точки:

```
 Ellipse target;  // круг
            Canvas maincanvas; // на котором рисуется точка
            SineWaveProvider32 sineWaveProvider = new SineWaveProvider32();

            public Target(Point center, double radius, Canvas canvas) // конструктор класса точки 
            {
                target = new Ellipse();
                target.Width = radius * 2;
                target.Height = radius * 2;
                Canvas.SetLeft(target, center.X - radius);
                Canvas.SetTop(target, center.Y - radius);
                target.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));

                sineWaveProvider.SetWaveFormat(16000, 1); // 16kHz mono
                sineWaveProvider.Frequency = 500;
                sineWaveProvider.Amplitude = 0.1f;
                waveOut = new WaveOut();
                waveOut.Init(sineWaveProvider);
                waveOut.Play();
                maincanvas = canvas;
                canvas.Children.Add(target);
                Panel.SetZIndex(target, 100);
            }
```

Если раскоментить, то не сохраняется в файл, если так оставить, то пишет ошибку, что невозможно преобразовать в UI элемент :(

Comment: Рано или поздно при работе напрямую с контролами в WPF возникает ситуация, когда вообще не понятно, как это работает. А все потому, что WPF очень сложный и неудобный, если писать код в Winforms стиле. А что делать, чтобы стало легче - учить MVVM и Data Binding (привязка данных).

Comment: Подсказка: сохраняйте файлы правильно `using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\soh.txt")) { здесь ваш код сохранения в файл }` и надо убрать `writer.Close()`. То же самое с чтением файлов. А так, пока не понятно, как оно работает, `Save` - это обработчик события? Какого события? Зачем скрыли оригинальное название обработчика? Ну и вот - [привязка данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/data-tools/bind-wpf-controls-to-data-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял, еще раз можете объяснить более подробно? Для меня тема эта новая. То есть я должен в обработчик кнопки должен вставить то, что написали и внутри код? Попробовал два варианта, все равно показывает ошибку... Может я неправильно употребляю GetTop или GetLeft? Пишет, что также не может преобразовать...

Comment: Сейчас напишу простой пример

Comment: Хорошо, жду ответа!

Comment: Ответ я дал, но удалил его, потому что вы никак на него не реагировали.